# A Sine Wave By Another Name? Calculating The Rate Of Change Versus Sine Wave Math?

Tags: calculus

So let's say you have a sine wave that is going to start at 0 and progress by 1 degree increments to 90 degrees. The radius will be 1 unit.

For visualization purposes a little car(I'm totally going off the rails already) will move along the x axis based on the return values from the Sine wave function. This value will essential be the cars speed. The car will travel a total distance of 1 unit based on the radius value.

At 1 degree the car will be moving near as fast as it ever will. At 89 degrees it will be barely crawling as it approaches the finish line.

Since the "speed" doesn't correlate in a linear fashion to distance traveled (i.e. at 30 degrees you'll have traveled 50% of your total distance) is there a way to predict car's position at, let's say 70 degrees, without doing the sine math and instead predicting the non-linear rate of change of the "speed" itself?

If we know the distance traveled over 90 iterations can we mimic sine wave math through another formula?

Thanks much for humoring a non math guy that loves math regardless!

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your question. At $70^\circ$, the position of the car is $\sin(70^\circ)$. You want to compute this value *without* using the sine function?

Comment: You can actually use the process of integration to determine an exact value itself. If you have velocity $v = \sin(x)$, then your position will be determined by the function $s = -\cos(x) + 1$. Alternatively, if you don't like working with sine waves, there is the concept of Taylor Series, which turns functions into "infinite polynomials".

Comment: @Hyperion : Thanks much, I will take a look into your suggestions. I'm hoping to avoid complex math and use an approximation for a coding project to minimize overhead. So, Distance if speed(returned sine values) were linear = (distance traveled for 1 degree(0.017 unit)) x (current angle). Simulated Sine position = Distance if speed(returned sine values) were linear x (current angle x mysterious variable that mimics the deceleration as the Sine Wave approaches 90 degrees)?

Comment: As a non-math guy I've got one last shot at this, behold! As soon as the angle begins creeping up the sine value slowly starts decreasing progressively faster until we hit zero at 90 degrees. If we know that one degree = 0.017 units can't we just multiply 0.017 x the current angle and then subtract a number that has ramped up using exponential growth? Is the rate in which a sine wave grinds to a halt at 90 degrees standard exponential growth expressed as a negative force?